# Как сделать универсальный экшн на обработку ошибок?

Tags: angular, angular4, angular10

Хочу сделать базовый экшн на обработку ошибок, есть такой екшн логина в нем есть екшн логинЕррор , и есть куча похожих файлов екшынов. Я хочу что б каждый раз не писать логинЕррор или регистерЕррор, сделать универсальный еррор, что можно было его использовать в любом месте где нужно выводить ошибку. Подскажите как правильно, или саму логику. Спасибо)

```
export class LogIn implements Action{
    public readonly type = ELoginActions.LogIn;
    constructor(public payload: Login) {}
}

export class LoginSuccess implements Action {
    public readonly type = ELoginActions.LoginSuccess;
    constructor( public payload: any) {}
}

export class LoginError implements Action {
    public readonly type = ELoginActions.LoginError;
    constructor( public payload: any) {}
}



export type LoginActions = LogIn | LoginSuccess | LoginError;
```

Comment: https://xsltdev.ru/angular/ngrx/actions/

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Если я создам отдельный файд где будет только один экшн на обработку ошибок, то как я его смогу вызвать в разных редюсерах?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin То есть я хочу что б у меня не было кучи одинаковых методов только с разными названиями, а хочу что б был универсальный на все случаи